# Getting position of a set bit in an integer

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm using the following trick to iterate through the bits set of an int:

```
    while (b != 0)
    {
        c = b & (0 - b);
        //Do something...
        b = b ^ c;
    }
```

Taking as an example the number 4128 (binary 0001000000100000) this works fine because c's values are 32 and 4096.

However, instead of the actual values I would like the positions of those values, these being 5 and 12.

Is there an extra line of code that can be inserted into the loop that will return the position?

Comment: Have you considered using a plain old `for`-loop?

Comment: You can use `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` to get the bit-index.

Comment: @harold That should be an answer really. Very nice.

Comment: @harold To avoid extra lines of code this your suggestion should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` to get the bit-index, like this:

```
while (b != 0)
{
    c = b & (0 - b);
    int index = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(c);
    //Do something...
    b = b ^ c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an efficient answer, but to honour the trick you are using. I changed it to `b &= (b - 1)`.

```
int bitCount(int b) {
    int bits = 0;
    while (b != 0) {
        int nextb = b & (b - 1); // Remove the rightmost bit 1

        int power2ofBitIx = b ^ nextb; // Get the lost bit   10..0
        int bitIx = bitCount(power2ofBitIx - 1); // And count 1..1
        // Do something with bitIx

        b = nextb;
        ++bits;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Jerry Coffin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142867/finding-bit-positions-in-an-unsigned-32-bit-integer).

You can get positions of set bits of an int using an mask and AND-ing each bit:

```
int c = 4128;
int two_32 = pow(2, 32);
for (int mask = 1, iter = 1; mask < two_32; mask <<= 1, iter++)
    if (c & mask)
        printf("Flag: %d set\n", iter);
```

This should print:

```
Flag: 0 set 
Flag: 5 set
```

Comment: The above code works, however it loops through all the bits instead of jumping straight to the bits set like in my original loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to make a bitboard game you shouldn't be needing the positions of the bits but the values.

I never saw your while loop before, nice one. Personally I like this one:

```
int tst = 255;

for(int looper = tst, i = Integer.highestOneBit(looper); looper != 0; looper &= ~i, i = Integer.highestOneBit(looper))
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean isBitSet(int position) {

```
    int value = Integer.parseInt("0000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(value));
    b = b.setBit(4);
    return b.testBit(4);
```

}

Comment: Hi, your answer doesn't seem to be correct. The `position` parameter isn't used.

It's good to have some text explaining your answer, not just a block of code.